# Place MYSQL data into session variable to pass to next page

Tags: php, mysql, variables, session

I'm new to the world of PHP and have been researching things for days but appear to be stuck.

Im attempting to setup a small website to act as a customer account area with a MySQL database at the backend.

I have a webpage with a login form where a user enters their username and password. There is a php script that checks the SQL database to see if there is a match, if there is redirects them to the account page. I found a sample script online which i used to create this and this part works great.

I'm trying to take things a bit further and display data from the matched SQL record on the webpage. From the research ive done it appears the best way to do this is to pass session variables to the account page.

Here is what I have setup

Page 1 - index.php 
This is a login page with a form that has entry for username and password. On submit, it runs checklogin.php

Page 2 - checklogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$host="localhost:3306"; // Host name 
$username="**********"; // Mysql username 
$password="**********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="galactek_myecl"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="clients"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// set variables
$_SESSION['office_name'] = mysql_query("SELECT office FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'");


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to   file "login_success.php"
session_register("username");
session_register("password"); 
header("location:myecl.php");
}
else {
header( 'Location: http://www.galactek.com/support/offmaint.html' );
}

?>
```

Page 3 - myecl.php
This is the page where I would like to display that data. Currently im trying to display just the Office Name but it keeps coming up as 0. If I hard-code the office name into the variable on the checklogin.php page, it comes across no problem.

```
<?php
session_start();
//if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
// header("location:index.php");
// }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>You're HERE!</p>

<?php

echo $_SESSION['office_name']

?>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm fairly certain im overlooking something. I haven't had much exposure to PHP to be able to distinguish what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `$_SESSION['office_name']` and see what it contains. Because you are assigning resources to it.

Comment: I'd try `var_dump($_SESSION['office_name']);` That would let him see everything.

Comment: You need to fetch the result from the resources.

Comment: Also, @MattLeach, is your myecl.php page totally blank? Because that would suggest to me that Tony's suggestion below is the culprit.

Comment: When in doubt `var_dump()` it.

Comment: Lol,@MichaelMcPherson i missed the var_dump in my first comment.

Comment: $_SESSION['office_name'] returns nothing

var_dump($_SESSION['office_name']);  returns int(0)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: As stated im fairly new to php and this is just sample code I foud. I guess ill spend some more time learing to use what has not been depreceated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here:

```
$_SESSION['office_name'] = mysql_query("SELECT office FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'");
```

The function `mysql_query` does not return a string, but an object containing the result of the query. (See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).) But in fact you already have the office in a result from a previous query, so there is no need to do another one. You can just use the variable `$result` from the first query you made:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to   file "login_success.php"
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); //Get an array with the results.
    $office = $row["office"]; //Get the office.
    session_register($office); //Register the office with the session.
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password"); 
    header("location:myecl.php");
}
```

Some further notes:

First, the `mysql_` functions should be avoided. They are deprecated and will be removed. On top of that they are prone to security issues. It is recommended to use PDO or MySQLi instead. [Here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) is a good beginners guide on MySQLi.

Second, `session_register("username");` does not register the variable `$username` but the literal string `"username"`. I am not sure that is what you want to do.

Third, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) says the following about using `session_register`:

> **Warning:** This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Consider using code like this instead:

```
$_SESSION['office'] = $row["office"];
```

Comment: In regards to the session_register("username") that was part of the sample code I used.

Comment: using your example above, would I still use $_SESSION to show the variable on the myecl.php page?

Comment: Then perhaps that is what you want to do. Anyway, I have added a comment about using `session_register`.

Comment: Yes, you would use `$_SESSION['office']`.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as your echo statement in myecl.php needs a semi-colon?

Comment: I think that would cause a syntax error, and not a `0` being echoed.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask questions.